# Ignore HTML tags by specified name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have small function that returns me html path

```
getDomPath = function(el) {
  var count, element, path, selector;
  count = void 0;
  element = void 0;
  path = void 0;
  selector = void 0;
  element = el;
  if (!(el instanceof Element)) {
    return;
  }
  path = [];
  while (el.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && el.id !== "jobs") {
    selector = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if (el.id) {
      selector += "#" + el.id;
    } else if (el.className) {
      selector += "." + el.className;
    } else {
      count = $(el).prevAll().length + 1;
      selector += ":nth-child(" + count + ")";
    }
    path.unshift(selector);
    el = el.parentNode;
  }
  return path.join(" > ");
};
```

It works well, but sometimes i have in my code tags like `<style>` or `<title>`. How do i skip this tags in my javascript function, so it wont count them to my nth-child?

For ex. i have following code

```
<table>
<sometag></sometag>
<tr>
<p>My paragraph here</p>
<tr>
</table>
```

So as result of this function i want to be

```
table:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(1)
```

but instead i would get

```
table:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > p:nth-child(1)
```

because script counts all previous elements

Comment: have you tried nth-of-type() instead of nth-child ?

Comment: Or something like `count = $(el).prevAll(':not(sometag)').length + 1;`

Comment: @JasonP, how can i pass array or sometag values?

Comment: See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). _All selectors are accepted inside :not(), for example: :not(div a) and :not(div,a)_

Comment: Also how do i pass tag name instead of class || id ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JasonP, he said i can do in following way 
`count = $(el).prevAll(':not(sometag)').length + 1;`